# Implementing Delegated Permissions with Managed Identities in Azure: Retrieving Tokens for User Impersonation

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-ad-msal, azure-managed-identity, msal

I'm in a situation where I'm not sure how to proceed. In our application landscape, we're implementing Managed Identities for our microservices. Currently, I'm working on an API (API-1) where I grant access to the database and other resources based on a System Assigned Managed Identity. However, this API also needs to retrieve some of its data from another API (API-2) with delegated user_impersonation permissions.

I can retrieve a token on behalf of the user in API-1 using the following code:

```
    var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientInformation.ClientId)
        .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{clientInformation.TenantId}")
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret);

    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(currentAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

    var application = builder.Build();
    var onBehalfOfBuilder = application.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion);
    var authenticationResult = await onBehalfOfBuilder.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

However, this code uses an AppRegistration (ClientId/ClientSecret), and minimizing the use of ClientSecrets is precisely what we aim for with the implementation of Managed Identities. Is there a piece of code or configuration where we can retrieve a token on behalf of the Managed Identity for the user, utilizing the delegated user_imperonate permission? The only thing I can find is setting Application permissions on the Managed Identity using a PowerShell script.

Question 1: Is it possible to assign delegated permissions to a Managed Identity?

Question 2: Am I making a conceptual mistake by attempting to retrieve a token from a backend API using delegated permissions?

Comment: You should be able to assign app permission (vs delegated permission) to the managed identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: Is it possible to assign delegated permissions to a Managed Identity?

No.

> Question 2: Am I making a conceptual mistake by attempting to retrieve a token from a backend API using delegated permissions?

Not necessarily, on-behalf-of flow is meant for this scenario.
Managed Identities do not support on-behalf-of.
You can only request a token for a certain resource from the Managed Identity endpoint, it's not possible to specify the token you received.

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting, but not the one I was hoping for. So, when I intend to utilize the on-behalf-of flow, I am required to utilize app registrations and maintain their client secrets.

Comment: Yes, or client certificates.